# Android: how to change layout_x, layout_y in an AbsoluteLayout dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, absolutelayout

I have a fixed background-image and showing another image on top of it.
Here is the xml-

```
<AbsoluteLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
 <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/test_image"
     android:src="@drawable/lpch_1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
<ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/search_pin"
     android:src="@drawable/pin"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_y="100px" 
     android:layout_x="100px"
        />  
 </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Now, how can I change the layout_x, layout_y of image-id search_pin from code?

Comment: why you use absolute layout ?

Comment: having co-ordinate data for image in a CSV and need to position the image on that position. so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = ((AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) test_image.getLayoutParams());
params.x = 100;
params.y = 100;
test_image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 3):

Absolute Layout is deprecated.

For this case, i would suggest to use **FrameLayout**.

One more thing, **dp** or **dip** is more preferrable other than **px**.

As android support multiple screen resolutions, its not good to mention fixed co-ordinates for a particular widget.

Comment: actually I need to plot the image over another, in an absolute position( getting layout_x, layout_y from CSV). So, which layout should I use? Let me know, if i need to ask that in a separate question.

Comment: check my updated answer,and yes i have already mentioned that use FrameLayout for the same.

Comment: ok. let me check. really thanks. u could hv like my question though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Absolutelayout` intead of `relativelayout`:

`android:layout_x="100dp"` **not px**

`android:layout_y="100dp"`

both used for `absolutelayout`.